# Does the target in ln -s have to be a full path?

Tags: linux, shell, ln

I've tried to invoke `ln` in directory `~/download` as this:

```
ln -s ./abc ~/abc [EDITED]
```

but it does't work.
I do `ls -al` in  my home and get wrong link of `abc`.

```
ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
```

So my question here is: Does `ln` need full path of the target?  I didn't find any document or hint in the `man` page. If so, where can I get further information.

Comment: why do you want to make hardlinks? They're nearly never a good idea.

Comment: You ask about `ln -s` but your example uses just `ln`; which are you dealing with?

Comment: I want to make a symbolic link, typo there.

Comment: @bmargulies That's not true. They just have different purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s quite simple: You create a symbolic link in `~` that points to `./abc` *in that directory*. The pathname of a symbolic link must be valid in the context of the directory it is in¹. If you indeed want to point to the file that is in your *now current* directory, you must use the full path.

---

1. The link must be valid if you want to use it. It can point into nothingness or to a file that does not exist. That can be a good thing, as the file might have been there before and can reappear any time, and the symbolic link will then point to it again.

Answer (score 2):

`ln` can take either absolute or relative pathnames; the difference matters for symbolic links, but since you asked to make a hard link, it will resolve to the same file either way.

Check the `ls -li` output on `~/abc` and `~/download/abc` -- you'll see that the link count is `2` and the inode number is the same for both files.

Comment: sorry, typo.  I just want make a symbolic link. I encounter this problem when creating symbolic link.

Comment: Ah, then [MPI has your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10427564/377270). Please take this as a learning opportunity to copy and paste what you _actually_ tried, not just what you think you tried. :)

Comment: this learning opportunity is more precious than "ln" knowledge.

Comment: Hehe, I'm glad you think so :)